# Bison parser crashes during compile time, reports "Error 1"

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

my bison build fails during compile time without much information.

It says: `error: shift/reduce conflicts: 1 found, 0 expected` although from my understanding those bison normally tolerates.

The error boils down to the second **if production** `IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement ELSE statement`.
As soon as I add these it crashes during compile time.

Thankfull for any input.

```
%start          translation_unit

%%
translation_unit
  : external_declaration
  | translation_unit external_declaration
  ;


external_declaration
  : function_definition
  ;


argument
  : IDENT COLON IDENT
  ;


argument_list
  : argument
  | argument_list COMMA argument
  ;


function_definition
  : FUNC IDENT LPAREN argument_list RPAREN compound_statement
  | FUNC IDENT LPAREN               RPAREN compound_statement
  ;


compound_statement
  : LCURL                RCURL
  | LCURL statement_list RCURL
  ;


statement_list
  : statement
  | statement_list statement
  ;


assignment
  : IDENT ASGN IDENT SEMIC
  ;


declaration
  : VAR IDENT COLON IDENT SEMIC
  ;


expression
  : IDENT
  | LIT
  ;


if
  : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement
  | IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement ELSE statement
  ;


statement
  : declaration
  | assignment
  | compound_statement
  | if
  ;
%%
```

Comment: Is that your complete bison file? You really don't declare any of your tokens? Not declaring the tokens will produce many errors

Comment: The tokens are defined above. I just cut it for simplicity. Like stated, it depends solely on that second if production as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you don't provide complete details, it's very hard to help you. Your bison file, augmented  by what I think is necessary to define the tokens, does not crash on my machine; it generates the expected parser and header file. So if you want someone to investigate, please add complete information: a complete file which produces the symptom which troubles you and the precise command you used to invoke bison. The bison version would also be helpful.

Comment: Note: If your bison file is full of actions, it's fine to delete them. That's what a [mre] is. Just make sure that the minimal file you provide shows the same problem as you report.

Comment: (Also, I suppose that "Error 1" is being reported by the make utility, not by bison. But it would be helpful to be clear. If that's the case, you might have to dig into the Makefile in order to say what the precise bison invocation was.) The bison version (`bison --version`) and invocation are particularly important if this actually is a bison bug, which is what it sounds like (although it's quite likely that "upgrade to the latest version" is the fix, in that case).